# jquery & php: saving some data without reload

Tags: php, jquery

I have three buttons and need to save some data. I have a idea, I have to set an ID to every button and then let the JS determinate witch button that has been pressed, like:

```
$("#mySpecifikButton").click(function()
{
....some code here...
});
```

but then Im stuck. For example I have 9 users. All they have an ID in the db. So now we have all the users in separate rows:

```
<p><a id="userID">user 0</a></p>
<p><a id="userID">user 1</a></p>
<p><a id="userID">user 2</a></p>
<p><a id="userID">user 3</a></p>
...
```

When I press on a specifik user I want to add it to db through php with help of jquery. 
But how do I sent it to php with JS (jquery)?

Im I thinking right or is there better ways?

If I didn't described it well, ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, you can use Ajax to send the value of the button that has been pressed to the php script. Search the [jQuery site](http://jquery.com) for documentation on $.get and $.post. :)

Edit: Now that I'm not on my iPod, it'll be much easier to type. :P

Here's what I mean:

```
<input type="button" value="Button 1" id="1" />
<input type="button" value="Button 2" id="2" />
<input type="button" value="Button 3" id="3" />
<input type="button" value="Button 4" id="4" />
```

Then, use some JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[type=button]").click(function() {
  $.post("myPHPscript.php",{buttonID: $(this).attr("id")},function(d) {
    //d is the response from the PHP page.
    //Do something with it!
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: d will contain the output of the php script. instead of d, you might want to use response as it's a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

As it sounds like you are making changes to the database, I would recommend using the `$.post( url, [data], [callback], [type] );` [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post#urldatacallbacktype). You can just post a form to the server and deal with it like you would any other form post.

Answer (score 0):

You doesnt have to use jquery for that . Its simple through ajax .

user 0

user 1

user 2

user 3

------------------------------script.js File------------------------------------

```
var xmlHttp;


ajaxFunction(id){

url = anypage.php?Sentid=id; // here you are sending id through GET to any simple db connection mysql and php based page to add to db or anyother function.

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged; xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true) xmlHttp.send(null)

}//end of function


function stateChanged(){        
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete" ){       // any operation you want to perform here

    }//end of if 
}//end of function


function GetXmlHttpObject(){    
var xmlHttp =null; 
var xmlHttp =null; 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){

          // If IE7, Mozilla, Safari, etc: Use native object
          var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()    
}   
else    {   
    if (window.ActiveXObject){

          // ...otherwise, use the ActiveX control for IE5.x and IE6
          var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
          }

    }    
    return xmlHttp;
 }//end of function
```

Comment: If Adis is already using jQuery (from the looks of the question this is the case) then this would seem like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to send a request to a PHP page (as mentioned above with `$.post`). The easiest way is to have a PHP page - let's say /insert.php:

```
<?php
    some_insert_function($_REQUEST["userid"], ...);
?>
```

then use:

```
function go(el) {
    $.post("/insert.php?items="+el.id);
}
```

**EDIT:** You should also add some visual indication that the data has been sent - at least a statusbar message ( `setStatus("Sent data")`, although these don't always work ), but preferably a colour change or message-in-a-div.